# When applied to an interp1d cubic spline `find_peaks' returns index position not values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have data which I have applied a cubic spline using interp1d (assuming x and y have been previously defined)

```
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
xnew = np.linspace(start, end, num=501, endpoint=True)
spline = np.array(f2(xnew))
```

if I check this I get the values I am expecting

```
print(spline)
[ 2.737e-02  5.0504e-02  ....]
```

However, I need to identify peaks in the spline and am using find_peaks from Numpy Signal

```
peaks = signal.find_peaks(spline)
```

But this returns a series of index positions whereas I am trying to return the actual peak values of the spline array.

```
print(peaks)

(array([ 15, 123, 290, 432]), {})
```

Reading the documents (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) 
this doesn't appear to be the expected behaviour (although it is entirely possible I have misunderstood).  Any suggestions?

Comment: It returns what the docs say it returns, see docs you linked under "Returns". Anyway, if you want the values instead just do `spline[peaks[0]]`.

Comment: Im and idiot...!  Thanks Paul, and you quite right - clearly states 'returns indices'.  I thought the example scripts where plotting values, whereas it as actually plotting index positions.  Also you suggestion worked perfectly.  Thanks